# In Ruby is there a way to tell where a method is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby is there a way to tell where a method is defined? I'm going through the ruby-guides and there is a line of code that  reads `Post.all` How can I tell where `all` is defined?

Answer (score 18):

If you want to know the file and line where the method is defined, use

```
Post.method(:all).source_location
```

It will give you `[file, line]` or `nil` if it's a C method.

Answer (score 7):

A method can be used via a Method object. Which at that point as an `owner` attribute. So you can do something like this:

```
puts Post.method(:all).owner
```

That will tell you the module/class that defines the method.

Comment: that doesn't work for me - I just get the class back, even if the method was defined in an included module

Comment: it would be Post in your example, even though :all was defined in some other module